# How to get low resolution image urls from json:api?

Tags: 8

The json:api put provides a link to file--file node types, but the url is to the original image file.

How can I get a lower resolution image file via json:api to avoid users from downloading a MB+ image file?

Answer (score 1):

Core does not support this (yet... hopefully).

Assuming you have [already set up image styles](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/structure-image-style-create.html), you can use the [Consumer Image Styles](https://www.drupal.org/project/consumer_image_styles) module, which is the approach taken by [Contenta CMS](http://contentacms.org/).

For reference, there's also [a blog post on the background to the development of Consumer Image Styles](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/decoupled-drupal-hard-problems-image-styles).